# Running autotools in Windows (MinGW)

Tags: c++, c, makefile, mingw, autotools

I am trying to build the [shapelib](http://shapelib.maptools.org/) from [source](http://download.osgeo.org/shapelib/shapelib-1.4.1.zip) on Windows. The library uses autotools. I have MinGW installed with the appropriate packages. When I run

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sh autogen.sh
```

it outputs

```
autogen.sh: line 4: readlink: command not found
autogen.sh: line 4: dirname: command not found
**Error**: Directory `' does not look like the top-level package directory
```

I don't expect readlink to work with Windows so I just skipped right to

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sh configure
```

However, that also throws errors

```
configure: line 478: sed: command not found
configure: line 477: expr: command not found
configure: line 478: sed: command not found
configure: line 492: sed: command not found
: error: cannot create .lineno; rerun with a POSIX shell
```

Is there any hope of getting this to compile on windows? Am I missing something obvious? I double checked and the sed package is installed.

[image]

Comment: Note that in a proper Autotools project, one is not obligated to rebuild the build system (which is what `autogen.sh` traditionally does) in order to build the software itself from an unmodified distribution.  In fact, it is usually best to avoid doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved. My MinGW install was corrupted. I removed MinGw and installed it again. Now `autogen.sh` runs fine.